# Is this word a correct English word?

Tags: word-choice

Is "containingly" a valid word in an English sentence, if not what's the right word?

Example: I explicitly and containingly want ...

This will be the beginning of a text block regarding a specific subject. It shouldn't really matter whether that subject has a broad meaning or just a simple rule. But I welcome any suggestions/words.

Comment: What exactly do you intend it to mean?

Comment: A word that means such thing as- to cover and contain what I'm going to write next to that. A word that should provide some written protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is *inclusively.*

Comment: *Inclusively* would almost certainly be an improvement over *containingly*, but it is still rather unclear what it would be to inclusively want something. What is supposed to include what?

Comment: Explicitly and completely.